# Regex - match to obtain words before and after \r\n

Tags: python, regex

Why doesn't my regex match?

```
SOURCE[\s]*[:]*[\s]*(\r\n|\r|\n)*[\[#x3000\]]*[A-Za-z \!\.\-]*
```

Text

```
\xa0SOURCE:\r\nHult International Business School\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSUBJECT: ENTREPRENEURSHIP (92%);
```

My regex tries. it seems to work nearly okay here.
http://regex101.com/r/aB7nJ2

For some reason, only a [\s] captured the \r\n. i don't understand why. using [\s]* solved it.

Comment: Two tips when diagnosing regex's: 1) as you've seen below, seeing the code context is very important as depending on how you've quoted, which language/regex library you're using, etc. the answers can be quite different, 2) when making a complex regex, always start with something simple that you can get to match, and build up from there, rather than trying to write the whole thing and debug it all at once. By the time you're ready to take it to StackOverflow, you should be able to narrow the problem down to the specific part of your regex that isn't doing what you expected. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your regex pattern [defined with a raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)? If so, it should match:

```
In [25]: import re

In [26]: text = '\xa0SOURCE:\r\nHult International Business School\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSUBJECT: ENTREPRENEURSHIP (92%);'

In [27]: re.search(r'SOURCE[\s]*[:]*[\s]*(\r\n|\r|\n)*[\[#x3000\]]*[A-Za-z \!\.\-]*', text)
Out[27]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0xb0bffa0>
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation):

> Raw string notation (r"text") keeps regular expressions sane. Without
>   it, every backslash ('\') in a regular expression would have to be
>   prefixed with another one to escape it.

Comment: I am use raw string... r'{0}[\s]*[:]*[(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)]*[\[#x3000\]]*[A-Za-z \!\.\-]*(?:\s)' it doesn't work. i get 'SOURCE:\n'

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the text you are processing, and what your goal is? Your current regex may be overly specific which makes it complex. Complex is bad because it is hard to write, hard to understand, and thus hard to maintain. Maybe there is a simpler way to approach the real problem.

Comment: A regex is a pattern meant to match multiple strings. You've only shown us 1 or 2 strings, which may be trivial to match but won't solve your real problem because we have no notion of what parts of the string may change and what remains constant. To really help you, we need to see a comprehensive set of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Missing some escaping?

```
SOURCE[\s]*[:]*[\s]*(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)*[\[#x3000\]]*[A-Za-z \!\.\-]*
```

Comment: Hm, I'm writing r'{0}[\s]*[:]*[(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)]*[\[#x3000\]]*[A-Za-z \!\.\-]*(?:\s)' but it doesn't work.